# How to get props of component when unit testing using jestjs

Tags: reactjs, facebook, testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am using shallow from enzyme. I want to get props that I have passed to component in my testing file. Like so in example but I am getting undefined.

```
console.log(wrapper.props())
```

should return object of props but it returning some jsx object.

Kindly assist how to get props of some component for which I want to write test cases.

Here is my code:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
    configure,
    shallow
} from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';

import MenuList from './MenuList';
import {
    Link
} from 'react-router-dom';

configure({
    adapter: new Adapter()
});

const footerItem = {
    label: '',
    links: [{
        label: '',
        link: '/'
    }]
}

describe('<MenuList />', () => {

            let wrapper;
            beforeEach(() => {
                    wrapper = shallow( < MenuList footerItem = {
                            footerItem
                        }
                        / > );
                    });

                it('should render Link', () => {
                    console.log(wrapper.props().footerItem); // This should print footerItem object but returning  undefined
                    expect(wrapper.find(Link).length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
                });
            });

// and here is the code of menulist component/


import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const menuList = (props) => {
    let linkArray=[];
        linkArray = props.footerItem.links.map((item,index)=>{
            return <li key={index}>
                    <Link to={item.link}>
                        {item.label}
                    </Link></li>
        })

   return (
        <div className="footer-link">
            <h6>{props.footerItem.label}</h6>
                <ul>
                    {linkArray}
                </ul>
        </div>
   )
}
export default menuList;
```

Comment: Not sure if this'll fix it but generally when rendering anything from react-router in a test you should wrap it in a `MemoryRouter`. See: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/guides/testing.md

Comment: @MichaelCurry This test case passed because I passed one object in props. I was more curious to get props of this test component. Is this any to to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent foo={10} />);
expect(wrapper.props().children).to.equal(10);
```

EDIT:

And like @Must keem pointed out, this works also:

```
const wrapper = mount(<MyComponent foo={10} />);
expect(wrapper.instance().props.foo).to.equal(10);
```

Comment: @Moyoto I have added component code there. I am using jestjs for expect here. So .to.equal(10) becomes .toEqual(10)

Comment: Hmm for me it seems right... What does it print if you console.log(wrapper.props()) or console.log(wrapper.debug()) or console.log(wrapper.dive().debug())

Comment: How ever I got props by wrapper.instance().props. I thought only wrapper.props() should work. Is there any reason why wrapper.props() is not giving props.